# Accordion menu - icon swap from src to data-src

Tags: javascript, jquery

Created an accordion based dropdown menu for mobile navigation.

1. when user clicks "li" it have to add class "active" to  tag. this works fine.
2. Also, it have to change icon to "white" instead "grey" --> Not working.
3. when user clicks already existing "active" or other "li", icon have to change as "grey" image instead "white" --> Not working.

Below are the code I used to fix the issue, but I am not able to figure out the solution.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu-accordion">
      <li>
      <a href="#"><img class="nav--icon" data-alt-src="images/nav-01_white.svg" src="images/nav-01_grey.svg" />Link 1<span></span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#"><img class="nav--icon" data-alt-src="images/nav-02_white.svg" src="images/nav-02_grey.svg" />Link 2<span></span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#"><img class="nav--icon" data-alt-src="images/nav-03_white.svg" src="images/nav-03_grey.svg" />Link 3<span></span></a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.menu-accordion li a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        newSource = $(this).find('li a.active img.nav--icon').data('alt-src');
    $('.menu-accordion li a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li a').addClass('active');
    $(this).data('alt-src', $(this).attr('src'));
    $(this).attr('src', newSource);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').addClass('active');
    nimg = $('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').attr("data-alt");
    oimg = $('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').attr("src");
    $('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').attr("src",nimg).attr("data-alt",oimg); 

    $('.menu-accordion li a').click(function(){

        $('.menu-accordion li').each(function(){
            if($(this).find("a img").hasClass("active") == true){
                $(this).find("a img").removeClass("active");
                oldimg = $(this).find("a img").attr("data-alt");
                newimg = $(this).find("a img").attr("src");
                $(this).find("a img").attr("src",oldimg).attr("data-alt",newimg);
            }
        });

        imgEle = $(this).find("img");
        newimg = imgEle.attr("data-alt")
        oldimg = imgEle.attr("src");
        imgEle.attr("src",newimg);
        imgEle.attr("data-alt",oldimg);
        imgEle.addClass("active");
    });
})
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<ul class="menu-accordion">
<li>
    <a href="#"><img class="nav--icon" data-alt="g.png" src="w.png" />Link 1<span></span></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#"><img class="nav--icon" data-alt="g.png" src="w.png" />Link 2<span></span></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#"><img class="nav--icon" data-alt="g.png" src="w.png" />Link 3<span></span></a>
</li>
```

1. I've changed data-alt-src to data-alt
2. $.each uses to remove current active class and swap images.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your code.. small changes.. <img> will not have "active" class name manually entered. On load i want to add "active" class name to second <li><a><img>. Also, image have to change to "g.png" on src. Instead "w.png".

Comment: Just do it.its working fine.Remove them and try.I put them only for checking.Create as many as them as u with.This code work for any number items.

Comment: On page load when i add "$('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').addClass('active');" it adds class name.. but image swap is not happening. as your code is only for click function bro

Comment: `$('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').addClass('active');`
`nimg = $('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').attr("data-alt");`
`oimg = $('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').attr("src");`
`$('.menu-accordion li a img:eq(1)').attr("src",nimg).attr("data-alt",oimg);`

Comment: Check the ***coding*** now.

Comment: Thanks for your great help bro!!